# Image upload failed to firebase database

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the code for taking the image, and the logcat error. I suspect there is problem with the permissions in phone. By default the application shows no permissions in phone. Is there a way to give permissions explicitly through the code?

[logcat error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJnjh.png)

[code used for taking image input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ARIx.png)

I checked  permissions on phone, I am developing this project by seeing an older video in youtube. So there is a chance of updation problem.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any issue with your application or device.
You haven't set proper permission on firebase storage.

Firebase storage requires user to be authenticated.
But if you are just testing Storage you can by-pass that rule.

In the Storage > Rules, add below code block,

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:**

It's good practice to protect the firebase storage with authentication. So after testing storage feature, please update rules accordingly.